# Representation of matrix A = BC

Tags: linear-algebra

This is straight from a textbook (Cullen):  Show that every $m \times n$ matrix $A$ of rank $r$ has a representation as $A = BC$, where $B$ is an $m \times r$ matrix whose columns are the first $r$ linearly independent columns of $A$ and where $C$ is an $r \times n$ matrix in row-reduced echelon form.  How is $C$ related to the row-reduced echelon matrix row equivalent to $A$?

From a theorem I know that if  $A_{n \times n}$ is nonsingular and $PAQ = I$, then $A^{-1} = QP$.  But this only works for nonsingular matrices. Can this idea be generalised or am I barking up the wrong tree here?

Comment: This sounds like LU factorization...or something related to it.

Comment: Thanks. It does and indeed it is.  My text is a bit old-school so does not use the LU terminology, but the idea looks the same.  I will see if I can tinker with some of the proofs to derive something for the singular case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let,

$A=\begin{bmatrix} 
A_1&A_2&A_3&\dots&A_n
\end{bmatrix}$

Here $A_i(1\le i\le n) $ are the columns of $A$.

Let $A_{i_{k}}(1\le k\le r)$ be the *first r independent columns of A*.

Let $B=\begin{bmatrix} 
A_{i_1}&A_{i_2}&A_{i_3}&\dots&A_{i_r}
\end{bmatrix}$

Let $C=\begin{bmatrix} 
C_{1}&C_{2}&C_{3}&\dots&C_{n}
\end{bmatrix}$ ($C_i$ are the columns of C)

$A_1=A_{i_1}$(As we can always select a set of $r$ independent vectors from a set of $n$ vectors spanning a $r$ dimensional space such that a particular vector $v$ is always there).

Now I will show that for some if $BC$ equals to $A$ then $C$ will be in its row reduced echelon form.

We must have $C_1=\begin{bmatrix} 
1&0&0&\dots&0
\end{bmatrix}^t$

$A_2$ is either $kA_1$ for some $k\in F$ or $A_2$ and $A_1$ is linearly independent in which case $A_2=A_{i_2}$(Because $A_{i_2} \in$ set of first $r$ independent columns of $A$)

With similar arguement one can establish that $A_{p}=\sum_{j=1}^{k}a_jA_{i_j}$(with some $a_j\ne 0$) or $A_p=A_{i_{k+1}}$. Here $\{A_{1_1},A_{i_2}\dots A_{i_k}\}$ is the minimum spanning subset of $\{A_1,A_2,\dots , A_{p-1} \}$(By a minimum spanning subset $S$ of $T$ I mean that $T\subseteq \text{span} (S)$ , $S\subseteq \{A_{1_1},A_{i_2}\dots A_{i_r}\}$ and there is no $W\subset S$ such that $T\subseteq \text{span} (W)$).

From this it easily follows that $C$ is Row reduced echelon form.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this out in detail. I have taken a much simpler approach than this.  I used the fact that every $m \times n$ matrix can be represented, uniquely, in its row reduced echelon form.  Then, the row reduced matrix is my C and the product of the inverse elementary matrices is my B.  That is, $A = BC$ where $B = (E_k...E_2E_1)^{-1}$ and $C = E_k...E_2E_1A.$

Comment: Elementary matrices are always square matrices. And in this case it is $m\times m$ so $B$ according to your answer is $m\times m$ and as $C$ is the row reduced echelon form of $A$ so it is a $m\times n $ matrix. So if $r<m$ then I guess your proof doesn't prove the claim in the question.

Comment: You are right.  I will have to come back to this - I've lost you a bit in the last paragraph when you introduced $p$ and $W$.  Are you able to give an example of this?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is tagged as homework, I am not providing every detail in the following.

Suppose $x$ and $y$ are vectors and $x^TAy=1$. Then you can show that
$\mathrm{rk}(A - Ayx^TA)=\mathrm{rk}(A)-1$. (For a start, note that $Ay\ne0$ but
$(A-Ayx^TA)y=0$.)

Now an induction argument shows that if $\mathrm{rk}(A)=r$ then we can write $A$ as
$$
  A= Ay_1x_1^TA+\cdots+Ay_rx_r^TA.
$$
Therefore if $B$ is the matrix with columns $Ay_1,\ldots,Ay_r$ and $C$ is the matrix
with rows $x_1^TA,\ldots,x_r^TA$, it follows that $A=BC$. [This last step may seem strange. 
In fact it is another way of looking at matrix multiplication.]

This result is equivalent to the fact that any matrix of rank $r$ can be written
(usually in more than one way) as a sum of $r$ matrices of rank one.